# Cannot access specific shared file from specific machine

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, file-permissions

I have my Windows 11 workstation and another Win 7 workstation.
And windows 2019 server standard.

The server has “Data” folder and share it across the domain.
I can access all the file and subfolders from all of my endpoints.
But **only** 1 specific file cannot be accessed and **only** from my win 11, the win 7 can access it! Even with my own user(which means the problem is the endpoint?)

When I try I get the following message:

> Windows cannot access … Contact your network administrator to request access.

What I've tried so far:

1. File permissions
2. Restart **both** win11 and server
3. Log in as another user to my win11
4. Change file name
5. Remove and add permissions
6. Disable permission inheritance
7. Take file ownership
8. Clear CSC from regedit (windows KB942974)
9. Change file location to different folder
10. Remap as network drive
11. Access with server IP instead of dns name
12. Remove win11 workstation from the domain, delete computer account and rejoin
13. Change win11 IP and hostname(pc name)
14. Disable AV

Nothing works!
Some advice?

Edit:

[security tab of a file i can access:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEIIi.png)

[security tab of the file i **can't** access:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hiuh.png)

[Advanced security tab of the file i **can't** access:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMrHV.png)

[Effective access tab of the file i **can't** access:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRwZy.png)

Comment: If this specific file cannot be accessed by Windows 11, but other files in the same folder can, then please add to your post the screenshots of *Properties >Security* of this file and another one to compare.

Comment: I added the pictures and edited:) https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc

Comment: In the Advanced security tabs of both files, what do you see in "Effective Access"?

Comment: see nothing, you can see screenshot i added

Comment: You need to select your own user to see its Effective Access.

Comment: You are right, my mistake! updating the screenshot

Comment: The Effective Access is indeed none. Might this be a problem with your antivirus blocking access (or other security software)?

Comment: I have ESET and i disable it -still nothing, i also have Cylence and it is disabled as well

Comment: If you move the file to your computer, what happens?

Comment: The file is exe of a software, locally it does nothing without all the dependencies and dll's

Comment: The problem gets more complicated - I would guess that it is with a dependency that is inaccessible from the network. You might be able to locate it by tracing the execution using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: Locate the dependency? it should be executed from the server share; and it is working in all the other PC's i have. it is really complicated cus it seems that all good in all of the regular checks!

Comment: I would change the owner of the file you cannot access to that of either all Users or all Administrators on the domain. I would also create a copy of the file on a machine that can access the file.

Comment: We tried that too, didn't help...

Comment: @harrymc ty, looks like you were right!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so we just found the solution,
apparently we had a mistake thinking we stopped the another AV named Cylence, we checked it right now and it is the problem.

I personally have never seen AV causing file permission mess and raising Windows built in message.